# Marker population from address

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Following is my code which i am using to populate marker from the array address but its not showing any marker nor map to the respective div, Kindly let me know what i did wrong and how can i resolve this issue.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

  var myOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(54, -2),
    zoom: 6,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

  var addressArray = new Array("41 Green Ln, Handsworth, Birmingham, West Midlands B21 0DE, UK","BT27 4SB","Norwich");
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var markerBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  for (var i = 0; i < addressArray.length; i++) {
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': addressArray[i]}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: results[0].geometry.location
        });

        markerBounds.extend(results[0].geometry.location);
        map.fitBounds(markerBounds);
      } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });
  }    

});
</script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Are you seeing any console errors?

Comment: @CiananSims no, its my complete code , all i see is a blank screen, i tried to implement the code of this tutorial and copied as it is dont know why its not showing kindly help, http://www.rocketmill.co.uk/the-adding-markers-google-maps-tutorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for the map to display, you'll need to give `#map_canvas` an absolute width/height using CSS.

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sCvJk/